# Delete files atomically/transactionally in python

Tags: python, django, transactions

I need to do the following

- Delete many entities from a database, also those entities have a file associated with them saved into the file system, which are accessed also by the web server (images!).

The problem: File deletion might fail, I have all the files in a folder for the main entity (its actually a 1-N relation, being each one of the N the file owners). If I try to delete a file when the web server is accessing them, I will get an exception and the process will go in half, some images deleted, and some doesnt, leaving the system inconsistent.

Is there a way to to do something similar to a transaction but in the file system (either delete all files or don't delete any)? Or perhaps another approach (the worst plan is to save the files in the database, but it is bad)

Comment: OK, why not: 1) catch the exception and retry deletion until server allows it (stops accessing the file)? 2) wait until no files are being accessed and then proceed with deleting entries?

Comment: That was my first thought (loop until files all available) But this doesnt seem right at all. Was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Can you prevent the server from opening the files so you can delete them and then get back to "business as usual"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to transactionally delete multiple files on normal filesystems (you might be able to find esoteric filesystems where it is, but even if so I doubt that helps you. Apparently your current filesystem doesn't even let you delete a file that's being read, so presumably you're stuck with what you have!).

Perhaps you could save in the database not the file contents, but a list of which filenames in the filesystem "really exist". Refer to that list for anything that requires consistency. If file deletion fails, you can mark the file as "not really existing" and requiring future attempts at deletion, then retry whenever seems sensible (maybe an occasional maintenance job, maybe a helper process retrying each failure with exponential backoff to a limit).

For this to work either (a) your webserver must refer to the database before serving the file, or else (b) it must be OK for there to be a indefinite period after the file fails to delete, during which it may nevertheless be served. And of course there is also the "natural race condition" that a file that begins to be served before the deletion attempt, will complete its download even after the transaction is complete.

[Edit: Ah, it just occurred to me that "i have all the files in a folder for the main entity" might actually be really helpful. In your transaction, rename the directory. That atomically "removes" all the files, from their old names at least, and it will fail (on filesystems that forbid that sort of thing) if any of the files is in use. If the rename succeeds, and nobody else knows the new name, then they won't be accessing the files and you *should* be able to delete them all without trouble. I think. Of course this doesn't work if you encounter another reason for failing to delete the file, because then you might be able to rename the folder but unable to delete the file.]